# On finding all the positive integral solutions of $x^2+y^2=z^2+1$

Tags: equation-solving, number-theory

I am a new to *Mathematica*. My goal is to find many (if not all) positive integer solutions to the equation:

$x^2+y^2=z^2+1$

using *Mathematica*. However the problem is that I can only find a particular solution not many solutions of the given equation using `FindInstance`.

Can someone help or give the codes in finding the solutions of the given equation?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There are an infinite number of points that satisfy that equation. You can't list all of them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: thanks for your comment @Pickett. I want to find many of them using Mathematica.

Comment: You can pick values according to `Reduce[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + 1, {x, y, z}, Integers]`.

Comment: Thanks @Pickett will try it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not give a result in terms of triple (x,y,z).

Comment: @Jr, what does `Reduce[]` give you?

Comment: It only gives me equations for x, y and z. @Guesswhoitis.

Comment: I was telling you to post the output. This is because `Reduce[]` will sometimes post parametrized solutions, if you're lucky.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. `Reduce` does not parametrize the solutions in this case: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAVfL.png

Comment: @Michael, ah, now that's rather unhelpful output. What happens if you add a `Positive[]` restriction to all the variables? (How tricky these Diophantines are!)

Comment: It seems obvious that triples of the form `{1, n, n}` and `{n, 1, n}` are solutions for any integer `n`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Many of the cases disappear, but you get m_goldberg's solution plus an unhelpful bit, `(x | y | z) \[Element] Integers && ((x == 1 && y >= 1 && z == Abs[y]) || (x >= 2 && y >= 1 && z == Sqrt[-1 + x^2 + y^2]))`.

Comment: To all: Thanks a lot. I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Diophantus's approach

Diophantus (Book II, problem 9) gives parameterized solutions to `x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + a^2`, here parametrized by `C[1]`, which may be a rational number (different than `1`).  We can use his method to find solutions to the OP's case, `a == 1`.  Since Diophantus' method produces rational solutions, we have to clear denominators to get a solution in integers.  This complicates searching for solutions with `a == 1`.

```
ClearAll[diophantusII9, opcase];
diophantusII9[x_, y_] := Module[{t, t0},
   t0 = Solve[(t + x)^2 + (C[1] t - y)^2 == x^2 + y^2, t];
   {x, y, t + x, C[1] t - y} /. Last@t0
   ];
opcase[seedx_, seedy_] :=
  Module[{p, sol},
   sol = diophantusII9[seedx, seedy];
   Select[
    LCM @@ Denominator[#] # & /@ Abs[sol /. Flatten[
        Solve[# == 1, C[1], Rationals] & /@ Numerator@Together@sol,
        1]],
    MemberQ[#, 1] &]
   ];
```

Example:

```
diophantusII9[5, 7]
opcase[5, 7]
(*
  {5, 7, 5 + (2 (-5 + 7 C[1]))/(1 + C[1]^2), -7 + (2 C[1] (-5 + 7 C[1]))/(1 + C[1]^2)}

  {{25, 35, 43, 1}}
*)
```

Now, it is not the case that every `opcase[x, y]` produces solutions.  A necessary condition is for there to be a solution with `a == 1` is that

```
(x + Sqrt[x^2 + y + y^2])/y
```

is an integer.  Searching up to `x` or `y` equal to `50` yields `16` solutions:

```
With[{$max = 50},
     Flatten[
      opcase @@@ (Position[
          Table[IntegerQ[(x + Sqrt[x^2 + y + y^2])/y], {x, 2, $max}, {y, 
            2, $max}], True] + 1),
  1]
 ]
Subtract @@@ Total[Partition[%^2, {Length[%], 2}], {4}]   (* verify *)
Length@First[%]
(*
  {{10, 15, 18, 1}, {25, 35, 43, 1}, {40, 55, 68, 1}, {55, 75, 93, 1},
   {221, 119, 251, 1}, {70, 95, 118, 1}, {85, 115, 143, 1}, {100, 135, 168, 1},
   {115, 155, 193, 1}, {130, 175, 218, 1}, {476, 255, 540, 1}, {145, 195, 243, 1},
   {1184, 407, 1252, 1}, {160, 215, 268, 1}, {175, 235, 293, 1}, {731, 391, 829, 1}}

  {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

  16
*)
```

#### Improvement to Diophantus' approach

Note that the approach above misses solutions, such as `{4, 7, 8}` or `{14, 17, 22}`.  Indeed, I do not think it can produce `{14, 17, 22}`. Applying a little thought to Diophantus's method yields the following improvement to finding nontrivial solutions.  (A trivial solution is one in which `x` or `y` is `1`; there are no nontrivial solutions with `x` and `y` less than `4`.)

```
ClearAll[nontrivial];
nontrivial[a_] /; a >= 4 := Sort /@ Join[
  With[{d = Divisors[a + 1]},
   Select[{a, (# (a - 1) - (a + 1)/#)/2} & /@ d[[2 ;; -2]], VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &]
   ],
  With[{d = Divisors[a - 1]},
   Select[{a, (# (a + 1) - (a - 1)/#)/2} & /@ d[[2 ;; -2]], VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &]
   ]
  ]
```

Example:

```
Join @@ Table[nontrivial[n], {n, 4, 10}] // DeleteDuplicates
(*  {{5, 5}, {4, 7}, {7, 11}, {8, 9}, {9, 19}, {10, 15}}  *)
```

Here we find several thousand nontrivial solutions:

```
(sols = Join @@ Table[nontrivial[n], {n, 4, 1000}] // DeleteDuplicates) //
   Length // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.160005, 6602}  *)

AllTrue[sols, IntegerQ@Sqrt[#.# - 1] &]
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: May I ask where can I find a English translation of "Diophantus (Book II, problem 9)"?

Answer (score 5):

`FindInstance` supports an optional argument that defines how many instances it should find. For example, this code will find 10 distinct solutions to your equation:

```
{x, y, z} /. 
 FindInstance[
  x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + 1 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0, {x, y, z}, 
  Integers, 10]
```

> ```
> {{2, 1, 2}, {600, 1, 600}, {1, 69, 69}, {114, 1, 114}, {92, 1, 92},
> {558, 1, 558}, {1, 932, 932}, {1, 1, 1}, {996, 1, 996}, {1, 132, 132}}
> ```

Comment: exactly what I am looking for, thanks @shrx

Comment: To find the nontrivial solutions: `FindInstance[
 x^2 + y^2 == 
   z^2 + 1 && ! (x == 1 && y == z) && ! (x == z && y == 1) && 0 < x &&
   0 < y && 0 < z, {x, y, z}, Integers]`.

Comment: even simpler, `FindInstance[
 x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + 1 && 1 < x && 1 < y && 1 < z, {x, y, z}, Integers]` but note this and @2012rcampion form can only apparently find the one `{4,7,8}` solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Solution that finds pairs where both `x,y > 1`

The other solutions miss values where both `x>1` and `y>1`.  For example, `x=11`, `y=7`, `z=13`.

First, iterate through the pairs of integers.  I order the pairs `{1,1}, {2,1}, {2,2}, {3,1}, {3,2}, ...`:

```
pair[1] = {1, 1}
pair[n_] /; MatchQ[pair[n - 1], {x_, x_}] := pair[n] = {1, 0} pair[n - 1] + {1, 1}
pair[n_] := pair[n] = pair[n - 1] + {0, 1}

Table[pair[i], {i, 10}]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}} *)
```

Now test a pair for whether it satisfies `x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + 1`:

```
testXY[{x_, y_}] := IntegerQ[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 - 1]]

testXY[{11,7}]
(* True *)
```

Now generate a bunch of results:

```
Last@Reap[
  Do[ 
     If[testXY[pair[i]], Sow[pair[i]]]
  , {i, 1, 100}]
]

(* {{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {5, 5}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}, 
    {7, 4}, {8, 1}, {9, 1}, {9, 8}, {10, 1}, {11, 1}, {11, 7}, {12, 1}, 
    {13, 1}, {13, 11}, {14, 1}}}
*)
```

Obviously you'd have to run the algorithm forever to find all values.

### FindInstance doesn't work

If I run `FindInstance` but require both `x>1` and `y>1` then it gives an error:

```
{x, y, z} /. 
 FindInstance[
   x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + 1 && x > 1 && y > 1 && z > 1, {x, y, z}, 
   Integers, 5]

(* The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist. >> *)
```

I'd love to know why.  Seems like a bug.

### Diophantus' version

Michael E2 points out that Diophantus was interested in `x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + a^2`.  Here's some code:

```
triple[1] = {1, 1, 1};
triple[n_] /; MatchQ[triple[n - 1], {x_, x_, x_}] := 
      triple[n] = {1, 0, 0} triple[n - 1] + {1, 1, 1}
triple[n_] /; MatchQ[triple[n - 1], {x_, y_, y_}] := 
      triple[n] = {1, 1, 0} triple[n - 1] + {0, 1, 1}
triple[n_] := triple[n] = triple[n - 1] + {0, 0, 1}

testXYZ[{x_, y_, z_}] := IntegerQ[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 - z^2]]
```

Run (ignoring trivial cases where `y==z`):

```
Last@Reap[
   Do[
       If[
          testXYZ[triple[i] && Length@Union@triple[i] == 3], 
          Sow[triple[i]]],
     {i, 1, 1000}
   ]]

(* e.g. {17, 9, 3} *)
```

Comment: I've no idea, how I came to this, but as you're obviously right, I'll take down my answer.

Comment: Nice, Diophantus' solution to his problem Book II, 9, is $10^2+15^2 =18^2 + 1$.  (His problem is to solve $x^2+y^2 = z^2+a^2$ and his method does not always yield $a=1$)

Comment: Note that @2012rcampion has a use of `FindInstance` above that does find non-trivial solutions.  Not sure why theirs doesn't work and yours doesn't, though.

Answer (score 2):

the simple approach works ok if you just need the first few thousand..

```
 allxyz = Append[##, Sqrt[Total[#^2] - 1]] & /@ 
            Select[ Tuples[ Range[2, 1000], {2}] , 
            IntegerQ[Sqrt[Total[#^2] - 1]] & ];


 Show[{ListPlot[allxy[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]}]
```

[image]

Better...`FindInstance` is much happier if we give it a z value and find `x,y`: This generates  45,000 solutions in about 30 seconds.

```
 allxyz = Flatten[Table[  
            {x, y, z} /. # & /@ 
             FindInstance[x^2 + y^2 == z^2 + 1 && 1 < x && 1 < y,
                   {x, y}, Integers, 100], {z, 10000}], 1];
```

Comment: Thanks @george2079. Doing your codes in my mathematica using findinstance does not give an output, why is that?

Comment: version issue? Im using 10.1

Comment: That maybe is the problem since Im using version 7.

Comment: I like your way of simplifying the job for `FindInstance`; the graphic is a nice insight too, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a PE question, my answer is deliberately vague and incomplete. Consider rewriting the equation as $z^2 - y^2 = x^2 - 1$. Expand the left-hand side as $(z-y)(z+y)=p*q=x^2-1$, and identify $p=z-y$ and $q=z+y$. Thus, $z=(q+p)/2$ and $y=(q-p)/2$. The restriction of non-decreasing $x\le y\le z$ implies a lower bound on $q$ from $y=(q-p)/2\ge x$.

Use the following Mr.Wizard function `DivisorPairs` to get $\{p,q\}$ from $n=x^2-1$.

```
DivisorPairs[n_] := 
    Thread[{#, Reverse[#]}][[ ;; Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]] &[Divisors[n]]
```

Keep only those divisor pairs at or above the lower limit on $q$, then form triples $\{x,y,z\}=\{2x,q-p,q+p\}/2$. There are different criteria for selecting divisor pairs which give integer solutions, depending on the parity of $x$. Still, the final codes for even and odd $x$ are only two or three lines each.

Functions like `Reduce`, `FindInstance`, and `Solve` are amazing, but can be slow. Code based on divisor pairs will return all solutions as requested in this question's title, without a guess at the number of solutions such as required by `FindInstance`.